# Ciclo de Vida de Componentes Angular

Tags: componentes

Estou iniciando meus estudos em Angular e tentando entender o ciclo de vida dos componentes. Estruturei minha aplicação para rodar em um único módulo. E a navegação pelos componentes será através do recurso de Rota.

No meu AppComponent realizei a seguinte implementação:

```html
<MeuComponenteMenu></MeuComponenteMenu>
<div class="qualquer">
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
<MeuComponenteRodape></MeuComponenteRodape>
```

Então, no Html do MeuComponenteMenu:

```html
<a class="nav-link" href="/about" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
<i class="fas fa-table fa-fw"></i>
<span>Sobre</span>
</a>
```

No arquivo de configuração da Rota:

```html
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: Home},
  {path: 'about', component: AboutComponent}
];
```

Então adicionei um output de log nos construtores do AppModule e AppComponent. Sempre que navego entre as opções do meu Menu, os Componentes do Módulo e do Componente Principal (AppComponent) parecem ser instanciados. Pois ao conferir o log, vejo que os respectivos construtores foram executados.

Meu questionamento é o seguinte, esses componentes não deveriam ser instanciados somente uma única vez? A não ser que o usuário executasse manualmente um refresh na página?
Do jeito que está, nem as Injeções de Dependência funcionará.

Obrigado,

Answer (score 0):

Bom, deve ser um erro de principiante. Ao invés de usar o href eu usei o seguinte:

```html
[routerLink]="['/about']"
```

Alterei a configuração da rota:

```html
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'home', component: Home},
```

Vamo que Vamo!